# Using react-native-config with fastlane

Tags: react-native, fastlane, react-native-config

currently in my react-native app I configure two lanes using [`fastlane`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane): `beta` and `production`. I'm using [`react-native-config`](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) for different environment configs (stored in 2 files: `.env.beta` and `.env.production`). How can I let `fastlane` know which env file should be used for each lane ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get `react-native-config` to pick up the correct config file using the environment variables feature provided by `fastlane` by using `fastlane [lane] --env [beta|production]`.

Comment: It's working only when put .env files into fastlane folder.

Comment: This doesn't get passed to react native config, it gets passed to the fastlane process. In order to then pass it to react native config, ENVFILE should be set

Answer (score 5):

If you asking how to set environment variables before you call a command to build your app, you can do this in your `Fastfile`. In your `Fastfile`, before you call the `fastlane` action to build your app, set the `ENV['ENVFILE']` variable to point to your `.env.X` file. See the [react-native-config docs on environments](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#different-environments).

```
lane :build_beta do
   ENV['ENVFILE'] = '.env.beta'
   build_ios_app(...) # you may be using `gym` instead.
end
lane :build_production do
   ENV['ENVFILE'] = '.env.production'
   build_ios_app(...) # you may be using `gym` instead.
end
```

Better yet, if the lane is exactly the same, you may want to call it with the config option from the command line:

```
# call me from the command line like: `fastlane build_sonlexqts_app config:beta`
lane :build_sonlexqts_app |options|
   config = options[:config]
   unless %w(beta production).include?(config)
     UI.user_error!("#{config} is invalid. Please pass either 'beta' or 'production'")
   end
   ENV['ENVFILE'] = ".env.#{config}"
   build_ios_app(...) # you may be using `gym` instead.
end
```